# How to test observable Angular 2?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getTestData(): Observable<[{}]> {
        return this.http
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
            .map(res => res.json())
    }
}
```

and a simple component

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'todo-component',
    templateUrl: './todo-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./todo.css']
})

export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
    testList: Object; 

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { }

    ngOnInit() { 
        this.todoService
            .getTestData()
            .subscribe((testList)  => {
                this.testList = testList
            });

    }
}
```

and I am trying to test this

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { TodoComponent } from '../todo.component';
import { TodoService } from '../../todo/todo.service';

let todoService,
    fixture,
    comp,
    todoList = [],
    TodoServiceStub = { 
    getTestData: function() {
        return {
            userId: 1,
            id: 1,
            title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
            body: `quia et suscipit
                    suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum
                    reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam
                    nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto`
        }
    }
},
testDataFromService = { "someKey": "some Val"};

describe('Todo Component', () => {

    beforeEach(async(() => {

       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           declarations: [ TodoComponent ],
            imports: [
                BrowserModule,
                FormsModule,
                HttpModule
            ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: TodoService, useValue: TodoServiceStub
                },
            ],
        })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TodoComponent);
            comp = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

      todoService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TodoService);
            spyOn(todoService, 'getTestData').and.returnValue({ 
            subscribe: () => {} });
        });
    }));

    it('should get data from the http call', async(() => {
        comp.ngOnInit();

        expect(comp.testList).toBe(testDataFromService);
    }))
});
```

It gets:

```
Expected undefined to be Object({ someKey: 'some Val' }).
```

Tried to follow the docs but the comp.testList will be not filled.. If I try to debug this it seems like the service call is being done but in test I can't reach to resolve value.. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you didn't mock the service correctly.

Comment: @Aravind thnx! but I don't think so because as I add an another method to the service that gets a data from localstorage I can test it! So, the service is injected fine I guess..
If you mean mocking observable is not correct however, I would like to hear how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing 2 things.

1. you didn't mock your service correctly. It should return an `Observable` and not raw data. Use `Observable.of` to create an observable with existing data. It also should return an array and not a single object as that is what you defined in your actual service. Be sure to import the operator `Observable.of` if you do not have some sort of general import file for used rxjs operators.
2. After init you have to let the `Observable` return the data before you can check for its presence in the component. Use `fakeAsync` and `tick` for this.

Updated code:

```
import { TestBed, async, tick, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// if you have not already you should import the Observable.of operator for this test to work
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { TodoComponent } from '../todo.component';
import { TodoService } from '../../todo/todo.service';

let todoService,
    fixture,
    comp,
    todoList = [],
    TodoServiceStub = { 
    getTestData: function() {
        // return an Observable like you do in your actual service and return an array
        return Observable.of([{
            userId: 1,
            id: 1,
            title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
            body: `quia et suscipit
                    suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum
                    reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam
                    nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto`
        }]);
    }
},
testDataFromService = { "someKey": "some Val"};

describe('Todo Component', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {

       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           declarations: [ TodoComponent ],
            imports: [
                BrowserModule,
                FormsModule,
                HttpModule
            ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: TodoService, useValue: TodoServiceStub
                },
            ],
        })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TodoComponent);
            comp = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    }));

    it('should get data from the http call', fakeAsync(() => {
        comp.ngOnInit();

        tick();

        expect(comp.testList).toBe(testDataFromService);
    }))
});
```

Comment: 'It should return an Observable and not raw data' makes me understand it:) 
So I have just added:
spyOn(todoService, 'getTestData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(testDataFromService));

It works! Thank you!